# Unable to update server on VS code

Tags: mongoose

```
app.post('/update', (req, res) =\> {
   Demand.findOneAndUpdate({
          _id: req.get("id")
}, {
 job_name: req.get("job_name"),
 unit: req.get("unit"),
 creator: req.get("creator"),
 security: req.get("security"),
 med: req.get("med"),
 qualifications: req.get("qualifications"),
 skills: req.get("skills"),
 educations: req.get("education"),
 other: req.get("other"),
 trade: req.get("trade"),
 element: req.get("element"),
 experience: req.get("experience"),
 when: req.get("when"),
 where: req.get("where"),
 time_per: req.get("time_per"),
 start_date: req.get("start_date"),
 end_date: req.get("end_date"),
 work_type: req.get("work_type"),
 salary: req.get("salary"),
 email: req.get("email"),
 phone_number: req.get("phone_number"),
 }, {upsert: true,returnNewDocument: true})
 res.send("Done")
})
```

It will send to the server but it will not be updated in the server. It seem to be posted internal bout i am noy sure.